# Неправильно заполняется datagridview

Tags: c#, массивы, datagridview

Есть такой метод

```
    void Decrypt(char[] text, int index)
    {
        for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--)
            for (int j = 5; j >= 0; j--)
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = text[index];

    }
```

Вызываю его так

```
        char[] text = ОФЩЭЯЯЙПХЪЮЯЁКРЦЫЯГЖЛСЧЬБДЗМТШАВЕИНУ;
        for (int i = text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            Decrypt(text, i);
```

На выходе должно получится так,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но datagridview заполняется первым элементом "О" массива text. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Comment: Дак вы каждый раз перезаписываете всё поле)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас как сейчас алгоритм работает - берется последняя буква в массиве `text` - ей заполняется весь грид, берется следующая буква с конца - ей перезаписывается весь грид, и т.д. неудивительно, что у вас в конце все записано буквой О.

Переделаем:

```
static void Decrypt(char[] text)
{
    for (var index = 0; index < text.Length; index++)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows[index % 6].Cells[index / 6].Value = text[index];
    }
}
```

Достаточно просто вызвать эту функцию передав в нее массив символов. Должно заработать.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Только в вашем коде убрать надо "return result;", метод же void

Comment: Да мне лень GUI городить было, я на массиве проверял, просто забыл подчистить)